# For a custom type in Julia, how do i stop `show` from printing its fully qualified name?

Tags: julia

Say I have a type, `X`, and I overload its `show()`. When the type name comes up in other contexts, such as in an array, it still prints the fully qualified name:

```
julia> module M
           struct X
               x
           end

           Base.show(io::IO, x::X) = print(io, "X($(x.x))")

           println([X(1),X(2)])
       end
Main.M.X[X(1), X(2)]
Main.M
```

Is it bad form to overload `show(::IO, Type{X})` to stop doing that? Is there a way to do that only in certain contexts (such as, if it's nested inside another object in the same module)?

```
julia> module M
           struct X
               x
           end

           # NOTE: Here I ONLY overload the Type printing, because the rest of the default behavior works great.
           Base.show(io::IO, x::Type{X}) = print(io, "X")

           println([X(1),X(2)])
       end
X[X(1), X(2)]
Main.M
```

Answer (score 4):

When making a custom type, like a `struct`, the author of the custom type often provides a version of `Base.show` specialized to that type. Here is a good pattern to follow:

```
struct MyString
    s::String
end

mystring = MyString("my string") # shows: MyString("my string")

# this is used to handle a call to `print`
Base.show(io::IO, x::MyString) = print(io, x.s)
# this is used to show values in the REPL and when using IJulia
Base.show(io::IO, m::MIME"text/plain", x::MyString) = print(io, x.s)

mystring = MyString("my string") # shows: my string
print(mystring)                  # shows: "my string" 
mystring = MyString("my string") # shows: MyString("my string")
```

this information comes from a Discourse entry written by [Steven G. Johnson](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-function-display-does-ijulia-call-at-the-end-of-each-cell/33554/2#)

Comment: The third-from-last and last lines seem identical?

Comment: The MIME method is optional - nice discussion here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-custom-pretty-printing-1

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to overload `show` for *values* (like in Jeffry Sarnoff's answer), but think twice before overloading `show` for types. The concern is that if problems arise, you have recourse for digging more deeply into the underlying representation of a value (you can use `dump` or other means of inspecting its internals). In contrast, if you change how a type is displayed it is a one-way trip. Jeff Bezanson (who knows a thing or two about Julia) is famously allergic to modifying `show` for types; the only instance I'm aware of in which he's given it a nod is for the [Unitful](https://github.com/PainterQubits/Unitful.jl) package.

You do have some options. First let's modify your example a bit:

```
module M

struct X
    x
end

Base.show(io::IO, x::X) = print(io, "X($(x.x))")

f() = println([X(1),X(2)])

end
```

Initially, you get this:

```
julia> M.f()
Main.M.X[X(1), X(2)]
```

The reason it prints the module path is because `X` isn't known to `Main`. Let's change that:

```
julia> using .M: X

julia> M.f()
X[X(1), X(2)]
```

Now you can see it prints more compactly. Alternatively had you said

```
export X
```

in the definition of `M`, and then `using M` (or `using .M` depending on how you defined `M`), then it also won't show the path.

The rule is that if the name is defined in `Main` it won't show the module path. In terms of packages, *exported* quantities will print without the module qualifier.